# Retrieving Managed Package Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, managed-package

Is it there anyway to retrieve managed package components like aura components and lwc?

- I tried using VS Code but managed package components were not retrieved.
- I tried retrieving all LWC & Aura components through workbench but I
  am unable to view any managed package related components in the zip
  file.

Comment: If they are not "yours" (you / entity you work didn't author them), then no.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A subscriber cannot view the code of components included in managed packages and most of elements included in a managed package are protected (the may also be IP protected).

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm)

> Component Can be Updated During Package Upgrade:
>
> - If no: The component can’t be updated during package upgrades. Instead, it’s only deployed to the subscriber org during the initial package installation, and subsequent package upgrades don’t update the component. **Components in this category, can typically be modified by the admin in the subscriber org**.

> Component Has IP Protection:
>
> - If yes: To protect the intellectual property of the developer, the component’s metadata, such as Apex code or Custom Metadata record information, is hidden in the installed org.

If you look at [Lightning Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_lightning_component) you'll find

- Component Is Updated During Package Upgrade - Yes

Therefore Aura Component and LWC included in a managed package cannot be retrieved from a subscriber org.

The same goes for Apex Class, Trigger, Flow, etc...

Going through the linked page you can know what you're able to retrieve (and modifify) and what is protected.